# C++ Operator Overload with Value Reference

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I'm overloading a vector operator '-' and trying difference reference method. The code that test the operator is

```
pos-(norm-bias)
```

where pos, norm and bias are all instances of the class Vector.

Constant reference worked:

```
Vector operator-(const Vector& v) {
```

However, I don't understand why without the 'const' keyword would result in an error: Invalid operands to binary expressions.

```
Vector operator-(Vector& v) {
```

Furthermore, I don't understand why "const Vector&& v" with rvalue reference failed.

```
Vector operator-(const Vector&& v) {
```

Comment: Assuming bias is an lvalue, it will not be bound to const Vector&& without std::move (or explicit cast).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't provided much information, so I'm going to assume all 3, `pos`, `norm` and `bias`, are instances of `Vector`.

Let's consider the expression `pos-(norm-bias)`. First the subtraction within the parentheses is performed. Your `operator-` returns a new `Vector` object by value. So the result of the first subtraction will now try to bind to `pos.operator-()`. But rvalues cannot bind to non-`const` references and the code will not compile unless your `operator-` takes its argument by `const` reference.

Now if you change the signature to `Vector operator-(const Vector&& v)`, the very first subtraction, `(norm - bias)` will fail because `bias` is an lvalue and it will not be able to bind the rvalue reference parameter.

What you might want to do is provide two overloads, one that takes a `const` reference, and another that takes an rvalue reference.

```
Vector operator-(const Vector& v);
Vector operator-(Vector&& v);
```

In the second operator, you could potentially *steal* resources from the argument and avoid expensive operations such as memory allocation. Whether you could actually benefit from such an overload is impossible to tell without knowing what your `Vector` class contains and does.

Answer (score 0):

The correct overloads you want are:

```
Vector operator-(const Vector& v) const;
Vector operator-(Vector&& v) const;
```

Note that you want to mark the method themselfs as `const` as well, because otherwise you will run into more problems when you have expressions like `(pos-norm)-bias` (whether that example makes sense or not). In the long run, if you *really* want to exploit move semantics, you actually want to do more, as the left-hand side might also be movable and you want to complete the set of operators with `-=`. In the end, you probably want two member functions:

```
Vector& operator-=(const Vector& v);
Vector& operator-=(Vector&& v);
```

and a set of four free functions:

```
Vector operator-(const Vector& lhs, const Vector& rhs);
Vector operator-(const Vector& lhs, Vector&& rhs);
Vector operator-(Vector&& lhs, const Vector& rhs);
Vector operator-(Vector&& lhs, Vector&& rhs);
```

The latter can be improved/optimized further by having it automatically generated for you, consider using a library like [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) or my [df.operators](https://github.com/d-frey/operators/) to help you with that.

Generally, you might want to read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706) for operator overloading.